# Wordpress pods framework - importing custom settings pages with php

Tags: php, json, wordpress, import, custom-fields

I would like to import the pods settings using the functions.php file in my theme  I have a json file exported from pods UI

```
function import_pods_package($package_data) {
 // Check if Pods is active
 if ( !function_exists( 'pods' ) ) {
  return new WP_Error( 'pods_not_active', 'Pods plugin is not active' );
 }

 // Import the package
 var_dump(json_decode($package_data));
 $import = pods_api()->import( $package_data,);

 // Return the result
 if ( false === $import ) {
  return new WP_Error( 'pods_import_failed', 'Failed to import Pods package' );
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}


import_pods_package(get_template_directory_uri().'/general.json');
```

I tried this, but result is:: **Warning**: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **C:\laragon\www\wordpress\test\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\pods\classes\PodsAPI.php** on line **10668

i also tried to convert json file to csv and result is same.

If I have provided too little information, please let me know what else is needed

---

Answer (score 0):

For the current state of the `import(...)` function in `PodsAPI.php` see https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/blob/main/classes/PodsAPI.php

```php
/**
 * Import data from an array or a CSV file.
 *
 * @param mixed  $import_data  PHP associative array or CSV input
 * @param bool   $numeric_mode Use IDs instead of the name field when matching
 * @param string $format       Format of import data, options are php or csv
 *
 * @return array IDs of imported items
 *
 * @since 1.7.1
 * @todo  This needs some love and use of table_info etc for relationships
 */
public function import( $import_data, $numeric_mode = false, $format = null ) {

    // ... Doing something ...

    // If the $import_data is a CSV, then parse it
    if ( 'csv' === $format && ! is_array( $import_data ) ) {
        $data = pods_migrate( 'sv', ',' )->parse( $import_data );

        $import_data = $data['items'];
    }

    // ... Doing something ...

    // Gets default valid POD fields
    $fields = pods_config_merge_fields( $pod['fields'], $pod['object_fields'] );

    // ... Doing something ...

    // Loops through your $import_data
    foreach ( $import_data as $key => $data_row ) {
        $data = array();

        // Loops through default valid POD fields and try to find an equivalent filed in your $import_data
        foreach ( $fields as $field_name => $field_data ) {

            // If there is not an equivalent filed in your $import_data, jump into the next field
            if ( ! isset( $data_row[ $field_name ] ) && ! isset( $data_row[ $field_data['label'] ] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            // If there is an equivalent filed in your $import_data, apply its value to the current POD configuration

            // ... Doing something ...
        }
    }

    // Return the ID numbers of those valid fields which have been found in your $import_data 
    return $ids;
}
```

Your problem starts with the line 10668:
[image]

Clearly there is something wrong with the `$fields` variable. This variable contains the current configuration of your POD fields.

You can try to `var_dump` it to see what's wrong with it:

1. Go to `PodsAPI.php` and create a new function for testing purposes:

```
public function myTest() {
    /**
     * @var $wpdb wpdb
     */
    global $wpdb;

    pods_query( "SET NAMES utf8" );
    pods_query( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );

    if ( ! empty( $this->pod_data ) ) {
        $pod = $this->pod_data;
    } elseif ( ! empty( $this->pod ) ) {
        $pod = $this->load_pod( [ 'name' => $this->pod ], false );
    }

    if ( false === $pod ) {
        return pods_error( __( 'Pod not found', 'pods' ), $this );
    }

    $pod_name = $pod['name'];

    $fields = pods_config_merge_fields( $pod['fields'], $pod['object_fields'] );

    return $fields;
}
```

2. Go back to `functions.php` and `var_dump` the `$fields` variable:

```
function import_pods_package($package_data) {
    // Check if Pods is active
    if ( !function_exists( 'pods' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'pods_not_active', 'Pods plugin is not active' );
    }

    // Prints out the current POD fields configuration
    $fields = pods_api()->myTest();
    var_dump($fields);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Its returning "NULL". Any ideas why?

Comment: It's possible that the `$fields` variable has not been populated yet when you call the `import` and `myTest` methods, which could result in the variable being `null`. The `$fields` variable contains the configuration of the POD fields, which may not be initialized until after other parts of the Pods framework have been loaded. Try to put the `import` and `myTest` methods at the very end of `functions.php` or try to call `pods_api()->init()` before calling `import(...)` and `myTest()`